use jacoco instrument command to get probed class and it seems strange
this is source code
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println( "invoke invoke main" );
        while( true ) {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep( 1000 );
            System.out.println( new Date() );
        }
    }
}


this is the run command in IDEA
-javaagent:/Users/jiajie.zhuang/gitlab-idea/jacoco-debug/lib/jacocoagent.jar=includes=com.*,output=tcpserver,address=127.0.0.1,port=6300,append=true

use jacoco Instrument to get probed class, and it shows:
public class App {
    public App() {
        boolean[] var2 = (boolean[])"$jacocoData";
        super();
        var2[0] = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean[] var2 = (boolean[])"$jacocoData";
        System.out.println("invoke invoke main");
        var2[1] = true;

        while(true) {
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            var2[2] = true;
            System.out.println(new Date());
            var2[3] = true;
        }
    }
}

Why the static field $jacocoData and init method $jacocoInit() are not in the class file?
jdk 11
jacoco master
I run the source code in IDEA with the run-params, and I use Instrument to see the probed class file , but I can not find the $jacocoData and $jacocoInit() in it.
